# How to ensure a task has started before continuing?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, locking, task-parallel-library

I have a method that populates a shared collection and I invoke it in a `lock` and in a `Task` like this:

```
void PopulateCollection()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                _sharedDictionary = GetSharedDictionary();
            }
        });
}
```

I use the same `lock(_padlock)` around that collection whenever it's read.

The problem I'm having is that the `Task.Factory` may not have started its task (and so the lock may not have been obtained). This results in a race condition.

A reader method like this exists:

```
void ReadCollection()
{
    lock(_padlock)
    {
        DoSomethingWithCollection(_sharedDictionary);
    }
}
```

So my problem is that I have code like this:

```
...
PopulateCollection();
... // some things happen
ReadCollection();
...
```

I have no guarantee that the collection is populated before it's read because I cannot guarantee that the Task has started (and thus the lock has been obtained) before the collection is read.

I don't want to proceed until that lock has been obtained.

Comment: Why do you care about race conditions when you lock around the shared memory?

Comment: because the lock isn't obtained in time.

Comment: If it's obtained somewhere else then it will wait until the lock is free.

Comment: I edited the question with more detail to explain the issue

Comment: `I don't want to proceed until that lock has been obtained.` Do you want this or *you want to wait until collection is populated* ?

Comment: @L.B I only want to wait until the lock has been obtained. I **explicitly** want to continue before the collection is populated.

Comment: @ the downvoter: how should I improve my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the TPL properly to begin with, hence your problem.  You generally shouldn't need to be using `lock` very much at all when using the TPL.

Rather than mutating a shared variable within your task to set the result of an operation, have the result of that operation *set the result of the task*.  You can then hold onto a reference to that task and use its value when it is computed.

```
Task<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> PopulateCollection()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSharedDictionary());
}
```

You can then attach a continuation to that task to do something with the result after it is computed:

```
PopulateCollection()
    .ContinueWith(task => DoSomethingWithCollection(t.Result));
```

Comment: I need to use a lock in this case (as far as I can tell). This populate method is called in the constructor. I don't know when or if the collection will be read... but if it *is* read then I need it to have waited on the lock from the Populate method. This is, basically, async eager loading.

Comment: @Matthew No, you *don't* need to use the lock.  The `Task` class will take care of all of the synchronization for you.  If you are only conditionally doing the work than you simply store the `Task<Dictionary>` and conditionally apply the continuation.  When attaching the continuation the `Task` class is then responsible for ensuring that the processing is not run until the generation is complete, and that the data is passed properly, without any synchronization issues.  It really is that easy.  That's the whole *point* of using the TPL, it's able to handle all of this for you.

Comment: Perhaps I'll need to put in more of my code... The collection is populated in a class constructor. The class has a "Get()" method that returns the items (and waits if they're not yet populated)... I don't see how I can do it with the code you've specified. The continuing isn't in the same method as the populating.

Comment: @Matthew The continuation doesn't *need* to be in the same method that is doing the populating.  That's what makes `Task` so superior to more traditional callback based asynchronous programming models.  You just hold onto the task and add the continuation whenever you want.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this but now I do not see why the `.ContinueWith` is needed.... if I request `r.Result` won't the wait be required to continue?

Comment: @Matthew If you're okay with blocking the current thread, the `Result` will work too, you don't need a continuation.

Comment: Ok, so based on your answer I made the return type of the `PopulateCollection()` method the `Task<Dictionary>>` and I reference the returned *task* in a variable '_myTask'. Then in my `ReadCollection()` method I simply return `_myTask.Result` ... I **do** want to block the thread invoking the read until the population has completed.

Comment: There is a missing ">" on the first line of the first code block, but it won't let me make a single-character edit.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to return the `Task`, so that you can wait for the operation to *complete*, not for it to start, as you suggested. Something like:

```
Task PopulateCollection()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                _sharedDictionary = GetSharedDictionary();
            }
        });
}
```

```
var populateTask = PopulateCollection();
... // some things happen
populateTask.Wait();
ReadCollection();
```

If you populate the collection only once and then use it repeatedly, another option would be to change `_sharedDictionary` to `Task<YourDictionaryType>`:

```
void PopulateCollection()
{
    _sharedDictionaryTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSharedDictionary());
}

void ReadCollection()
{
    DoSomethingWithCollection(_sharedDictionaryTask.Result);
}
```

`Task` will take care of the necessary synchronization here.

Comment: I explicitly *do not* want to wait for it to complete. I only want to wait for the lock to be obtained.

Comment: @Matthew But you're only waiting for it to be obtained so that you can later wait for it to complete.  This is a method of waiting for it to complete that doesn't require it to have been started in the first place.  It removed the *need* for the problem that you have by solving your *actual* problem.

Comment: @Servy I think I'm understanding now. My reference becomes the task rather than the collection populated by that task.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to ensure, that the lock inside the task is obtained before the continuation of the flow outside the task, you can use AutoResetEvent:

```
   var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
               waitHandle.Set();
                _sharedDictionary = GetSharedDictionary();
            }
        });
   waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Right, danger here would be a deadlock

Comment: If there is a deadlock danger that you anticipate, you would have it with any approach, which tries to solve your problem. "Ensuring the lock is obtained" is always deadlock-prone.